# Keep a uiview highlighted ( change it's alpha ) until another one in tapped

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

How can i keep a UIVIew highlighted ( change alpha ) until another one is tapped? I have a uiscrollview in which i have loaded several uiview in order to achieve the thumbnail effect. I create them using this method :

```
        _thumbnailScroll.delegate = self;

        [_thumbnailScroll setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [_thumbnailScroll setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];

        _thumbnailScroll.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
        _thumbnailScroll.clipsToBounds = NO;
        _thumbnailScroll.scrollEnabled = YES;
        _thumbnailScroll.pagingEnabled = YES;

        NSUInteger nimages = 0;
        NSInteger tot=0;
        CGFloat cx = 0;
        for (nimages = 0; nimages < 5 ; nimages++) {
         //   NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"thumb%lu.png", (nimages + 1)];
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"newPics/thumb/thumb1.png" ]];
            if (tot==5) {
                break;
            }
            if (5==nimages) {
                nimages=0;
            }

            UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

            CGRect rect = imageView.frame;
            rect.size.height = 150;
            rect.size.width = 150;
            rect.origin.x = cx;
            rect.origin.y = 0;

            imageView.frame = rect;

           // NSString *propertyName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%lu", (unsigned long)nimages];
            //UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapGestureCapturedFor1:)];
            UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self    action:@selector(onSingleTapGestureRecognized:)];
            singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
            singleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
            singleTap.delegate = self;
//            [imageView add]
            [imageView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
            //[singleTap1 release];

            imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

            [_thumbnailScroll addSubview:imageView];
            _thumbnailScroll.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            // [imageView release];

            cx += imageView.frame.size.width+100;
            tot++;
        }
```

The above method initializes the image views inside the scroll view and adds a tap gesture to be captured in the following method :

```
- (void)onSingleTapGestureRecognized:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)singleTapGestureRecognizer
{

    UIView *tappedView = [_thumbnailScroll hitTest:[singleTapGestureRecognizer locationInView: _thumbnailScroll] withEvent:nil];
 // tappedView.alpha =1.0;

   // NSLog(@"image view tag %ld" , (long)tappedView.tag);

//    NSLog(@" Description %@ " ,   tappedView.description );
   // label.highlighted = YES;

    tappedView.alpha = 0.5;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 5.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
     tappedView.alpha = 1.0;;
    });
 }
```

Now this method highlights the tapped uiview for almost 5 seconds, i am trying to keep it highlighted until i tap on another uiview. How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this code:

```
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 5.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
 tappedView.alpha = 1.0;;
});
```

And replace with this:

```
for(UIView *view in _thumbnailScroll.subviews) {
    view.alpha = 1.0;
}
```

This prevents the alpha in your tapped view from going back to 1 after 5 seconds and ensures all the other views have an alpha of zero. Or for a more performant approach, set a pointer to the last view clicked, and instead of looping through each of your ScrollView's subviews, simply set the alpha of the view you've referenced to 1.0. So instead, you'd add a property called lastTappedView and then replace the above code with:

```
_lastTappedView.alpha = 1.0;
_lastTappedView = tappedView;
```

Comment: thank you so much for explaining it and for helping out many thankss

Answer (score 0):

```
 singleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
```

numberOfTouch is read-only.